# Forks and Processes in C

Tags: c, process, signals, fork

I am supposed to write a program that runs two scripts in two separate processes and returns which one finished first. Unfortunately, my program returns the slower process, which confuses me. I made sure that the pids were not 0, so that they weren't child processes. I then compared the pids of each process to the pid of the process that finished first, but for some reason, the slower program gets printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  if (argc != 3) {
    printf("Invalid number of arguments!");
    exit(1);
  }
  pid_t one;
  pid_t two;
  int status = 0;
  pid_t winner;

  char const *args[] = {"/bin/sh", argv[1], argv[2], NULL};

  if ((one = fork()) == 0) {
    printf("%s is starting.\n",argv[1]);
    execv(args[0], args[1]);
  }
  if ((two = fork()) == 0 && (one != 0)) {
    printf("%s is starting\n",argv[2]);
    execv(args[0], args[2]);
  }
  if (one != 0 && two != 0) {
    winner = wait(&status);
    if (winner == -1) {
      if (one == winner) {
    kill(one, SIGKILL);
    printf("%s wins by default!\n", argv[2]);
      }
      else if (two == winner) {
    kill(two, SIGKILL);
    printf("%s wins by default!\n", argv[1]);
      }
    }
    else {
      if (one == winner) {
    kill(two, SIGKILL);
    printf("%s is finished!\n", argv[1]);
    printf("%s is the winner\n", argv[1]);
      }
      if (two == winner) {
    kill(one, SIGKILL);
    printf("%s is finished!\n", argv[2]);
    printf("%s is the winner\n", argv[2]);
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: which path exactly gets called? The "%s wins by default" or "%s is the winner"?

Comment: The %s is the winner

Comment: Do those `execv` calls actually succeed? It looks like the 2nd arg is incorrect - it's the address of the first character of a character string but should be the address of the first of a sequence of pointers.